# Allure reports issues with multiple browser failure in assertion

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-grid, allure

I have a test which fails in both Firefox and Chrome. The order of execution is first Firefox and then Chrome.
But in the Allure report, when I click on the test suite, it shows an assertion error only for chrome.(Assertion Error: For value: chrome) is only displayed. For Firefox it is not displayed.

I am using JUnit maven configuration. Allure cli for generating the report. Allure version 1.4.11.

Comment: i can notice that the xml file generated by junit adaptor  only stores stacktrace of last browser exceuted.i t does not show all in case of multiple browser and devices.I am running my testcases in ie,chrome,firefox,ios,android using junit and selenium grid.I want reports browser wise and also if failure ,then assertion or any error should be shown browser wise.Currently only the last execeuted browser is shown.Please help.................

Comment: If the JUnit XML only contains information about one test failure, then is this actually a problem with Allure? Also, are you running on Selenium grid or anything like that?

Comment: Yes ,i am using selenium grid set up and using junit .

Comment: Please provide some code snippet for your assertions. I would expect that you're using either parameterized tests or separate test classes for each browser if they contain completely different logic.

Comment: i am using soft assertion from package org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.

code snippet of assertions-:

soft.assertThat(elements.getText(pageobjectlocator)).isEqualTo(
    "What type do you want to add?");
soft.assertThat(elements.isDisplayed(pageobjectlocator))
    .isTrue();

Comment: code snippet for multiple browser-:

Comment: for multiple browser -:
This is in one class --> Class A (Multiple browser)
if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
   capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
   capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Constants.FF_node_URL),
     capability);
  }

Comment: else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie10")) {
   capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
   capability.setBrowserName("internetexplorer");
   capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Constants.IE10_node_URL),
     capability);
  }

Comment: Now, initilisation code is in another class-:Class b(Initialisation)

@Rule
 public ListGenerator<String> Browser = new ListGenerator<String>(
   asList("firefox" , "chrome"));

Comment: @Before
 public void Start() throws Throwable {
  MultipleBrowser brow = new MultipleBrowser();
  brow.browser = Browser.value();
  brow.setuptest(Browser.value());

Comment: Now , the reports are ---->
Running without grid-> 
1.testcase with one set of data in 2  browser -: on pass,it will show one testcase passed.

Comment: Now , the reports are ---->
A)Running without grid-> 
1.testcase with one set of data in 2  browser -: on pass,it will show one testcase passed.(Correct)
2.On fail - it will show 2 testcase failed which shows assertions error in both the browsers seperately.say testcase 1 for firefox ,testcase 2 for chrome.(issue).
B)Using selenium grid: on pass,it will show one testcase passed.(Correct).
2.On fail-:It will show only one testcase .but assertion error only for chrome.as testcase is run in a sequence(firstly firefox and then chrome using grid)